# how to get conditioned output value from a table containing duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table  'system' like following:

```
+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | value | date        |
+------+-------+-------------+
| 1    | abc   | null        |
| 1    | xyz   | 20/8/2016   |
| 2    | ijh   | 15/07/2018  |
| 2    | mno   | 19/08/2017  |
+------+-------+-------------+
```

I want the output like this by running a sql query:

```
+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | value | date        |
+------+-------+-------------+
| 1    | abc   | null        |
| 2    | ijh   | 15/07/2018  | 
+------+-------+-------------+
```

If one of the duplicated id value has one null value in the date column then i want that particular row as output. If both the date column has value then i want the row which contains maximum date.

i have tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM system 
WHERE 
    date IS NULL OR 
    NOT EXSISTS(select max(date) from system) 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `not exists (select max(date) from system)` makes no sense - it's a complicated way of writing "false". `not exists` (or exists) test the **presence** of a row. `select max(...) from ..;` always returns one **row** (but maybe with  a null value in the _column_). And as it always returns one row, `not exists ()` will always be false

Comment: @jarlh i am using normal ms sql...i want to execute the query in a stored procedure to get the above output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical way to approach this type of query is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc nulls first) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You have not specified what database you are using, so I've use ANSI/ISO standard constructs.

`ROW_NUMBER()` produces a sequential number.  This starts again for each id -- starting at 1.  The number increments by 1 based on the `ORDER BY` clause.

EDIT:

SQL Server doesn't support `NULLS LAST`, so you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when date is not null then 1 else 0 end), date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: kindly suggest me a approach using a normal sql query using where clause if...else conditions.Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @swati . . . This *is* a very normal SQL query, using standard functions and functionality.

Comment: @swati: why do you think that is not a "normal" SQL query.

Comment: Could you please explain me what the 'seqname' represents ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff..thanks for the explanetion...but the above query is not working properly...if i remove the null first condition it is running otherwise it is throwing error near first and i hover over the query it is showing like the function 'row_number' takes exactly 0 argument(s)..Please guide me in this....

Comment: Can i use case statement inside partition by...if yes could you give me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

use union and aggregate function

```
   select id,value ,max(date) as date from t 
   where id not in(select id from t where date is null)
   group by id,value
   union
   select id,value,date from t where date is null
```

Comment: Will return 2 rows for ID = 1.